# Monostable multivibrator simulation

Tags: verilog

The `monostable` module implements a monostable multivibrator. It takes in three inputs (clk, reset, trigger) and outputs a single (`pulse`).

The trigger input triggers the module. When triggered, the output signal (`pulse`) will switch to a high position for a period of clock ticks, and then return to a low position. The pulse width of the output signal can be set via the `PULSE_WIDTH` parameter, which represents the period in clock ticks that the signal should stay high.

Now, what is happening is when it gets triggered, immediately output signal (`pulse`) is getting high.

When triggered, the output signal (`pulse`) should be high on the next active edge of `clk`. What changes can be done ?

```
module monostable(
        input clk,
        input reset,
        input trigger,
        output reg pulse = 0
);
        parameter PULSE_WIDTH = 20;

        reg [4:0] count = 0;

        wire countReset = reset | (count == PULSE_WIDTH);

        always @(posedge trigger, posedge countReset) begin
                if (countReset) begin
                        pulse <= 1'b0;
                end else begin
                        pulse <= 1'b1;
                end
        end

        always @(posedge clk, posedge countReset) begin
                if(countReset) begin
                        count <= 0;
                end else begin
                        if(pulse) begin
                        count <= count + 1'b1;
                        end
                end
        end
endmodule



module monostable_tb();

reg clk;
reg reset;
reg trigger;
wire pulse;

parameter PULSE_WIDTH = 20;

monostable imonostable(.*);

initial begin
    clk=0;
    forever #50 clk=~clk;
end

initial begin
    $monitor("trigger=%b  pulse=%b, count = %0d",trigger,pulse,imonostable.count);
    $dumpfile("monostable_tb.vcd");
    $dumpvars(0,monostable_tb);

    trigger=1'b0;
    reset = 1'b0;    

    @(posedge clk) reset = 1'b1;
    @(posedge clk) reset = 1'b0;  
    @(posedge clk) trigger=1'b1;
    @(posedge clk) trigger=1'b0;

    repeat(25) @(posedge clk);

    $finish;
end  
endmodule
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified design which sets the output one cycle after the input trigger pulse, and keeps the output high for 20 cycles:

```
   module monostable(
            input clk,
            input reset,
            input trigger,
            output reg pulse = 0
    );
            parameter PULSE_WIDTH = 20;
    
            reg [4:0] count;
    
            always @(posedge clk, posedge reset) begin
                    if (reset) begin
                            pulse <= 1'b0;
                    end else if (trigger) begin
                            pulse <= 1'b1;
                    end else if (count == PULSE_WIDTH-1) begin
                            pulse <= 1'b0;
                    end
            end
    
            always @(posedge clk, posedge reset) begin
                    if(reset) begin
                            count <= 0;
                    end else if (pulse) begin
                            count <= count + 1'b1;
                    end
            end
    endmodule
```

It now uses a single clock signal, instead of 2.  It also uses a simple reset signal, which can avoid potential glitches causing unwanted asynchronous resets.

You should also use nonblocking assignments in the testbench:

```
@(posedge clk) reset  <= 1'b1;
@(posedge clk) reset  <= 1'b0;  
@(posedge clk) trigger<= 1'b1;
@(posedge clk) trigger<= 1'b0;
```

Comment: I think your improvement on my original design is quite good. Would you submit it as a pull request to the Monostable repository so others can use? https://codeberg.org/wbg/Monostable

Answer (score 1):

If a 1-clock synchronous delay is needed, then run the output thru a flip flop.

```
    module monostable(
        input clk,
        input reset,
        input trigger,
        output reg pulse = 0
);
        parameter PULSE_WIDTH = 20;

        reg [4:0] count = 0;
        reg reg_pulse_temp;

        wire countReset = reset | (count == PULSE_WIDTH);
      
        always @(posedge trigger, posedge countReset) begin
                if (countReset) begin
                        reg_pulse_temp <= 1'b0;
                end else begin
                        reg_pulse_temp <= 1'b1;
                end
        end

        always @(posedge clk, posedge countReset) begin
                if(countReset) begin
                        count <= 0;
                        // reset the flop
                        pulse <= 0;
                end else begin
                        if(pulse) begin
                        count <= count + 1'b1;
                        end
                end
          
          // flip flop
          pulse  <= reg_pulse_temp;
          
        end
endmodule
```